# Error: Cannot read property of undefined (Vue)

Tags: vue.js

I want to give data from one component to another. Therefore the first component should emit the BusEvent when Data is updated. The updated function is called, but I always get an Error in my console: Error in updated hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined"

The other component also doesn´t receive height/width. And I get the same error here: TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined.

I just started learning vue and I don't understand whats wrong. Thanks a lot for your help!

height and width are getting initialized in component one, so that can't be the problem.

```js
//Definition of EventBus in main.js file
export const EventBus = new Vue(); 

//First Component
import EventBus from '@/main.js'
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {    
      height: '',
      width: ''
    }
  },

  updated() {
    EventBus.$emit('emited', this.height, this.width);
  }
}


//Second Component
import EventBus from '@/main.js'
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      height: '',
      width: ''
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    const self = this
    EventBus.$on('emited', function (height, width) {
      alert('WORKS!')
      self.height = height
      self.width = width
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you define your EventBus in main.js?

Comment: I did it like that: export const EventBus = new Vue();

Comment: You should import it like `import { EventBus } from '@/main.js'` then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. EventBus should be imported like this `import { EventBus } from '@/main.js'`
2. If you want to pass multiple values via `$emit` you should use object.

Replace

`EventBus.$emit('emited', this.height, this.width);`

with

`EventBus.$emit('emited', {height: this.height, width: this.width});`

and then for listener:

`EventBus.$on('emited', function ({height, width}) ...`